# How to solve no mapping error in springMVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

I know there is already someone asked the question but I don't get any solution so please help me
When i use @ResponseBody is work porfact but when i try to return i view it not working properly
I practice simple spring web app some reason I can't able to mapped a view

**Error**

> Dec 16, 2019 11:25:54 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
>   WARNING: No mapping for GET /SpringMVC/WebContent/WEB-INF/View/cricket.jsp

**Controller**

**SonController.java**

```
package com.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
@EnableWebMvc
@Controller
public class SonController {

    /*@ResponseBoady is need when we just return string  */
    @RequestMapping(path = "/cricket")
    public String son() {
        return "cricket";
    }

}
```

**FrontController-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd">
<mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.controller"></context:component-scan>
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/View/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

**web.xml(DispatcherServlet)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" version="4.0">
  <display-name>SpringMVC</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>

  </welcome-file-list>
  <absolute-ordering></absolute-ordering>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>FrontController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FrontController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**cricket.jsp(View)**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Sachin is GOAT of Cricket</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To start, use Spring Boot. Your tutorial is out of date.

Comment: Thanks, I agree with you